# Relative positioning with position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I have a `<input />` field and an `<a><img /></a>` icon which I want to put inside the input.

Of course I can't put an image inside of the input since it's not that kind of tag, but I'd be happy with it just overlapping.

If I use `position: relative` (which makes positioning it correctly easy) the icon continues to take up invisible space where it would have been.

If I use `position: absolute` I cannot position the icon relative to its previous sibling, the positioning values are in relation to the parent, which is not great because different browsers render the `<input>` with different sizes.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/u7DUv/

Wrap the `input` and `a` in a wrapper and absolutely position the `a` off the relatively positioned `div` wrapper.

CSS

```
input {
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 200px;
}
div { 
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
div a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    right: 0;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: @Bergi I have to make my code work for the older browsers and `z-index` helps absolutely positioned elements correctly layer in IE 7.

Comment: OK, but even if you need the property a value of 1 should be enough?

Comment: @Bergi Go big or go home. :) But yes 1 or 2 would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what to do now. I make a `<span>` where my icon was, it will have `position:relative` with no offset and it will contain the icon with `position:absolute`. This way the absolute offset from the span is effectively the relative offset wrt the page.

Comment: the image wont take up space within the `<input>` element. You might want to try `<div contenteditable="true">`

Comment: agreed with @iambriansreed best solution is make one more common wrapper for input and icon image

Comment: I posted this before you posted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative, and use padding-left as amount of image's width in input tag, there will not be hidden space.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a negative `margin-left` on the image element to let it show up above the input.